# How can I produce a distance matrix for large datasets using Google Script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently producing a script that will compare a list of around 90 addresses to each other. The result of the script should be a list that contains the time taken to travel to each address from each other.

I've run into a series of issues whilst trying to resolve this. The main issue is that resulting distance matrix will have 8100 elements. Google script's max execution time is 30 minutes and thus the script keeps timing out.

Any ways that I can improve the script to make it run faster?

The aim of this script is to produce a list with StartID, EndID and Time. I would then be able to filter the list to find addresses within an hour of each other.

Thanks!

```js
function maps(origin, destination) {
  var driving = Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING
  var transit = Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.TRANSIT
  var modeSet = driving
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .setMode(modeSet)
  .setOptimizeWaypoints(true)
  .getDirections()
  var result = directions
  return result;  
}


function GoogleMaps() {
 //get distance
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ABC");
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EFG");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastrow-1, 3);
  //var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 3, 3);
     //Origin is in row 2, column 3
  var values = range.getValues();
  var output = []
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i)
  {
    var loop1 = values[i]
    var start = values[i][1]
    var startId = values[i][0]
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      var loop2 = values[j]
      var end = values[j][1]
      var endId = values[j][0]
      var result = maps(start, end)
      var status = result.status
      try{
        var time = result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value / 60;
        var row = [startId, endId, time]
        output.push(row)
      } catch(err){
        Logger.log(err);
      }
    }
   }    
  var outputLength = output.length
  var outputRange = outputSheet.getRange(1,1,outputLength,3);
  outputRange.setValues(output);
}
```

EDIT: updated number of elements in list

Comment: 90 * 90 is 8100, how is this reduced to 3600?  Is getting the list above the loop the slow part of how you create the `output` array? Is the slow part the the creation of `ouptutRange`?, are any errors produced in the try/catch AND if so can you instead detect that condition logically which will be faster than a try/catch.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the 8100 elements. The dataset has been updated since yesterday so I was still thinking of the old numbers. I used the try/catch block to try and resolve another issue I was experiencing with the `result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value` aspect of the script. The 'legs' were producing an undefined error.

Comment: I would then suggest a check for that undefined `result.routes[0].legs === undefined` perhaps, and also why IS it undefined?

Comment: I tested the `result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value` against 3 rows and i got the results i wanted. This makes me believe that perhaps the issue is that legs can't function against such a large amount of values.  I'm not sure how to go about resolving this though.

Comment: How about doing this in Python (for example) so you won't have the timeout limitation?

Comment: I would if I could, but as most of our data is done in Gsuite, it seemed more efficient to produce the script using Gscript.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is reduce the number of operations you execute in your `for` loops. So let's start with analyzing that first, but from an algorithmic perspective.

In your current implementation, you're basically calculating the [Cartesian Product](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) on a set of 90 values to produce a new set consisting of 8100 values.

However, there are a number of redundant values in that result set, such that:

1. The result set includes calculations where the same address is used as both the starting and ending location.
2. The distance between 2 addresses is calculated twice; such that address A is the start address and address B is the end address and in another iteration address A is the end address and address B is the start address.

   ***CAVEAT: I'm making the assumption that you cover the same distance during transit between two addresses regardless of one's transit
   direction (ie. A-to-B or B-to-A). That may not be the case in your
   scenario.***

You can eliminate those redundancies by using an area of discrete mathematics called combinatorics; more specifically using this lovely formula:

[image: formula]

If we let ***n = 90*** and ***r = 2*** we get the following:

[image: formula]

That means, at our most optimal, we need an algorithm that produces no more than 4005 address pairs.

With that as our goal, [cracks fingers] its time to write a more optimal algorithm! But for illustrative purposes and in the interest of brevity lets use a smaller sample size of 4 addresses made up of one letter. The following array should suffice:

```js
var addresses = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Using the aforementioned formula we deduce there are 6 unique address pairs, which we can represent as follows:

```js
ab  bc  cd
ac  bd
ad
```

So how does one generate those pairs?

If you look at the representation above you'll notice a few things:

- The number of columns is one less than the number of addresses in the array
- With each successive column (from left to right) the number of address pairs per column is reduced by 1; ie. there are 3 pairs that start with 'a', 2 that start with 'b', 1 that starts with 'c'.
- Also note, that as you progress from one column to the next, successive columns do not have any pairs with the starting character of the previous columns; ie. the 2nd column does not have any pairs starting with 'a' and the 3rd column does not have any pairs starting with 'a' or 'b'

Let's generalize these observations. Given an array of ***n*** addresses we can generate ***n - 1*** columns. The length of each column shrinks by 1 such that the first column has ***n - 1*** pairs, the 2nd column has ***n - 2*** pairs, the 3rd column ***n - 3*** pairs etc., where each column consist of pair combinations that omit addresses from previous columns.

Based on those rules we can set up a `for` loop as follows (run the script and it will generate a collection of objects whose 'start' and 'end' properties represent unique address pairs):

```js
var addresses = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var pairs = [];
var numColumns = addresses.length - 1;
var columnHeight;
var columnIndex;
var rowIndex;

for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numColumns; columnIndex++) {

    columnHeight = numColumns - columnIndex;

    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < columnHeight; rowIndex++) {
        pairs.push({
            "start":addresses[columnIndex],
            "end":addresses[columnIndex + rowIndex + 1]
        });
    }
 
}

console.log(pairs);
```

So the above handles algorithmic optimizations, you'll need to tweak it for use with your implementation but it should serve as a good jumping-off point. However, while generating 4005 address pairs is relatively quick, processing those address pairs to find distance traveled via the Map API will likely be time intensive.

In the event that you still manage to exhaust the 30 minute script execution quota, you may want to consider using batch processing techniques, where you setup up your application to do calculations on smaller batches of address pairs, one batch at a time over a given period. You might even be able to process multiple batches concurrently if you setup your application correctly. But that's a post for another time.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had a go at trying to apply your suggestion to the code but I must be doing something wrong, as the script isn't assigning the addresses from the spreadsheet to the addresses array.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not any better than what you have for performance but try to break it down into a more modular solution here, then you can decide which part to optimize perhaps by doing it in some subset at a time;

```js
function getValuesArray(values) {
  let valueArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    valueArray.push({
      id: values[i][0],
      value: values[i][1]
    });
  }
  return valueArray;
}

function GoogleMaps() {
  //get distance
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ABC");
  var outputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EFG");
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastcolumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, lastrow - 1, 3);
  //var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3, 3, 3);
  //Origin is in row 2, column 3
  var values = range.getValues();
  var output = [];
  let list1 = getValuesArray(values);
  // deep clone
  const clone = (items) => items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : { ...item
  });
  // might only need list1 but usin two for clarity here
  const list2 = clone(list1);
  const listWork = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < list1.length; a++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {
      listWork.push({
          dest: list2[j].value,
          destId: list2[j].id,
          origin: list1[a].value,
          originId: list1[a].id
        }
      }
    }
  }
  let results = [];
  for (let w = 0; w < listWork.length; w++) {
    results.push(startId: listWork.originId, endId: listWork.destId, map: maps(listWork.origin, listWork.dest));
  }
  for (let r = 0; r < results.length; r++) {
    let result = results[r];
    // seems to not be used 
    //var status = result.map.status;
    let route = !!result.map.routes && result.map.routes[0] ? result.map.routes[0] : null;
    if (route !== null &&
      route.legs &&
      route.legs[0] &&
      route.legs[0].duration &&
      route.legs[0].duration.value) {
      let time = route.legs[0].duration.value / 60;
      let row = [result.startId, result.endId, time];
      output.push(row);
    }
  }

  let outputLength = output.length;
  let outputRange = outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, outputLength, 3);
  outputRange.setValues(output);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out once my daily execution is refreshed!